# AndroidStudio emulator does not work on macOS because "no Qt platform plugin could be initialized"

Tags: flutter, qt, android-emulator

Installed the latest version of Android Studio for macOS, all plugins and SDK updated to the latest versions. When launching any android emulator (I tried different API versions, version arm64-v8a) I get the error:

> handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. ((null): 0, (null)) emulator: INFO: ignore sdcard for arm at api level> = 30 emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp: 68: Warning: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in "/ Users / artmqq / Library / Android / sdk / emulator / lib64 / qt / plugins "((null): 0, (null)) emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp: 68: Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. ((null): 0, (null)).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved by reinstalling the android emulator in sdk tools